# Lower bound for the expected maximum of gaussian deviations

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, solution-verification

I want to show that for $w_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathcal N (0, 1)$:

$$\mathbb E\left [ \max_i^n |w_i| \right ] \geq (1-1/e) \sqrt{2\log n}$$

**my attempt:**

We have from Markov's inequality that:

$$\mathbb E \left[ \max_i^n |w_i| \right ] \geq t\mathbb P\left ( \max_i^n |w_i| \geq t \right )$$

for all $t>0$.

We also know that:

$$\mathbb P\left ( \max_i^n |w_i| \geq t \right ) = 1-(1-2\mathbb P(w_i\geq t))^n$$

From a [mills ratio type bound](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/) we know that:

$$\mathbb P(w_i\geq t) \geq \frac{t}{t^2+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}$$

Recall that $(1-1/n)^n$ is increasing towards $1/e$, all that remains to show is that for $t=\sqrt{2\log n}$ we have that the expression in the previous display is greater than $1/n$. But this is easy to show numerically.

**my question**

Have I made any mistakes here? Most of the proofs I have seen for this lower bound are much more complicated, for example: http://www.gautamkamath.com/writings/gaussian_max.pdf

Comment: It seems there is no mistake.